# why the carousel doesn't show other pages

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, carousel, tailwind-ui

i am using material tailwind and from that i built a carousel but it just show the first page and doesn't show other pages and i am sure the problem is not fromm the image cause i tried ither images and they doesn't work too
this is my code

```
            <Carousel className="rounded-xl h-96 mt-28 mb-28 w-11/12">
                <div className="relative h-full w-full">
                    <img
                        src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/234527/pexels-photo-234527.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=600"
                        alt="image 1"
                        className="h-full w-full object-cover"
                    />
                    <div className="absolute inset-0 grid h-full w-full place-items-center bg-black/75">
                        <div className="w-3/4 text-center md:w-2/4">
                            <Typography
                                variant="h1"
                                color="white"
                                className="mb-4 text-2xl md:text-2xl lg:text-2xl"
                            >
                                ارائه ی لایسنس های اورجینال
                            </Typography>
                            <Typography
                                variant="lead"
                                color="white"
                                className="mb-12 opacity-80"
                            >
                                لورم ایپسوم متن ساختگی با تولید سادگی نامفهوم از صنعت چاپ و با استفاده از طراحان گرافیک است چاپگرها و متون بلکه روزنامه و مجله در ستون و سطرآنچنان که لازم است
                            </Typography>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="relative h-full w-full">
                    <img
                        src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/234527/pexels-photo-234527.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=600"
                        alt="image 1"
                        className="h-full w-full object-cover"
                    />
                    <div className="absolute inset-0 grid h-full w-full place-items-center bg-black/75">
                        <div className="w-3/4 text-center md:w-2/4">
                            <Typography
                                variant="h1"
                                color="white"
                                className="mb-4 text-2xl md:text-2xl lg:text-2xl"
                            >
                                ارائه ی لایسنس های اورجینال
                            </Typography>
                            <Typography
                                variant="lead"
                                color="white"
                                className="mb-12 opacity-80"
                            >
                                لورم ایپسوم متن ساختگی با تولید سادگی نامفهوم از صنعت چاپ و با استفاده از طراحان گرافیک است چاپگرها و متون بلکه روزنامه و مجله در ستون و سطرآنچنان که لازم است
                            </Typography>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="relative h-full w-full">
                    <img
                        src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/234527/pexels-photo-234527.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=600"
                        alt="image 1"
                        className="h-full w-full object-cover"
                    />
                    <div className="absolute inset-0 grid h-full w-full place-items-center bg-black/75">
                        <div className="w-3/4 text-center md:w-2/4">
                            <Typography
                                variant="h1"
                                color="white"
                                className="mb-4 text-2xl md:text-2xl lg:text-2xl"
                            >
                                ارائه ی لایسنس های اورجینال
                            </Typography>
                            <Typography
                                variant="lead"
                                color="white"
                                className="mb-12 opacity-80"
                            >
                                لورم ایپسوم متن ساختگی با تولید سادگی نامفهوم از صنعت چاپ و با استفاده از طراحان گرافیک است چاپگرها و متون بلکه روزنامه و مجله در ستون و سطرآنچنان که لازم است
                            </Typography>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </Carousel>
```

i tried another images cause i thought it could be from image but it wasn't from images all image show in the first page but not in another pages